# Cauchy series "Product Like"

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, cauchy-product

If I have:

$$\sum_{q=0}^{+\infty}\alpha_q \sum_{r=0}^q \beta_r\gamma_{q-r}$$

Is there a way to manipulate this expression in order to simplify it or at least rewrite into another form?

I've just noticed that it looks like a sort of Cauchy product

$$\sum_{q=0}^{+\infty}\beta_q \cdot\sum_{q=0}^{+\infty}\gamma_q=\sum_{q=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{r=0}^q\beta_r \gamma_{q-r}$$

but of course is missing the term $\alpha_q$ unfortunately. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What do $\alpha_q$, $\beta_q$, and $\gamma_q$ look like? If $\alpha_q=x^q$ then you have a Cauchy product.

Comment: For "general" $\alpha_q$, you're going nowhere.

Comment: unfortunately $\alpha_q$ does not have a specific form is a general term. I suspected not so much things can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common representations are
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\alpha_q\sum_{r=0}^q\beta_r\gamma_{q-r}
&=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq r\leq q<\infty}}\alpha_q\beta_r\gamma_{q-r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\beta_r\sum_{q=r}^\infty\alpha_q\gamma_{q-r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\beta_r\sum_{q=0}^\infty\alpha_{q+r}\gamma_{q}\\
\end{align*}